# AWS ec2 instance tag names Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get the volume id  of an EC2 instance based on a tag letter, which I can do fine, but I then want to get the tag called name which is the description of the EC2 instance so i can then create a snapshot based on volume id and assign the EC2 instance description to it

```
#gets current date
$backupDate = Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd'

#Retrieve all volumes that should be backed up based on the Key called Backup with the Value of D
$backupVolumes = Get-Ec2Volume -ProfileName qa | ? { $.Tags.Key -eq "Backup" -and $.Tags.Value -eq "D" } | select -expand VolumeId

#This gets all instances running and lists them
$instanceName = Get-EC2Tag -ProfileName qa | ? { $.ResourceType -eq 'instance' -and $.Key -eq 'Name'}

#Backup each volume and apply tag information to the volume and snapshot
Foreach ($backupVolume in $backupVolumes)
{
    $snapshot = New-Ec2snapshot -ProfileName qa -VolumeId $backupvolume -Description "Backup for $instanceName - $backupDate"
}
```

Above is what i'm trying to run, so the first line grabs the `volumeid` based on the tag value of D then the second line grabs the instance name, But I want it to only get the instance name based on the volume id listed, so I can pass this onto the `Foreach` loop and set the `-Description`

Comment: What is the issue with your code?

Comment: I think you forgot your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for getting the `Name` tag from the instance needs to be within the loop, then it gets the Tag that is associated with each Volume:

I've also changed the way you are filtering, using `-Filter` rather than `where` is more efficient as it returns the filtered data directly.

```
$backupDate = Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$backupVolumes = Get-Ec2Volume -Filter @{ Name='tag:Backup';Value='D'}

foreach ($backupVolume in $backupVolumes) {
    $instanceId = $backupVolume.Attachment.instanceid
    $volumeId = $backupvolume.VolumeId
    $instanceName = Get-EC2Tag -Filter @{ Name='resource-id';Value=$instanceid} | Where-Object Key -EQ Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

    New-EC2Snapshot -VolumeId $volumeId -Description "Backup for $instanceName - $backupDate" -WhatIf
}
```

Note: You'll need to add `ProfileName` back in where appropriate, and remove `WhatIf` as this is only needed to test the code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had something similar in the end but this is a neater version!